# Returning varying models From Rest Endpoint

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2

**Background**

I am developing my first webapi2 rest interface for some products/batches/packs etc. I read this [excellent page](http://dev.billysbilling.com/blog/How-to-make-your-API-better-than-the-REST) on how to make a good rest api and i'm stuck on a few concepts and my googling skills have failed me.

I would like to give the developer the option to embed or sideload sub resources to prevent repeated api hits for child/sub-resource data (i.e return all packs with a batch).  I would also like them to be able to specify which fields they would like to return.

I'm used to a normal MVC/WebApi style of creating a Method and its own or shared ViewModel and sending down that in its entirety.  If I need to send less data I create a slimmer ViewModel.

**Question**

What return type do I put on the rest endpoint, is it just a JObject that I construct manually depending on what fields they've requested (and the developer has to rely on the documentation to figure out what it could return)?

Or do I create a fat view model and somehow mark the fields as optional with the ability for the JSON/XML converter to omit these fields if the value is null etc (but then how do I side-load sub-resources...)?

Thanks, Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use OData v4 so that I can allow the client-app to decide on what and how to consume the data i'm exposing.  It doesn't support sideloading (that i've discovered so far) but it allows me to  embed, filter and slim down any models easily.